# Access adb shell from ubuntu terminal not working

Tags: android

I am trying to access adb shell from ubuntu terminal for viewing sqlite db values. I am using the following command:

"cd /home/santhosh/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell"

But I am getting a response like this : NO Command adb found. I am new to linux terminal. what to do? I tried to put path also. But adb shell not working. What to do?

Comment: after you go into platform tools use ./adb

Comment: you will need your device connected while performing this action

Answer (score 3):

this wont work for terminal unless you use
./adb
or set classpath

so better use

"cd /home/santhosh/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools/"

then 
./adb shell